# Back button not working in react native navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am using react native navigation and I need to update back button design which I have achieved by following code

```
static navigationOptions = {
    title: '',
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: '#544849',
    },
    tintColor: 'transparent',
    headerLeft: <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}><Image source={require('../../img/close.png')} style={{marginTop: 10, marginLeft:10}} /></TouchableOpacity>
  };
```

But this way I get error **undefined is not an object(evaluating r.props.navigation)**

back button does nothing without onPress.

Comment: Are you using [react-native-navigation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation) or [react-navigation](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation)? Your code looks like the latter.

Comment: @MichaelCheng "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.11"

Comment: @AdnanAli Can you provide the complete code for the view.

Comment: I use react-navigation. it didn't show button on top in Release build. but Simulator and real iPhone works.

Comment: I use createStackNavigator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acourding to [docs for NavigationOptions](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-options#Two-Ways-to-specify-each-option) you can change your code like below.

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation, screenProps }) => ({
        title: '',
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: '#544849',
        },
        tintColor: 'transparent',
        headerLeft: <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}><Image source={require('../../img/close.png')} style={{marginTop: 10, marginLeft:10}} /></TouchableOpacity>
});
```

Comment: Thanks bennygenel for your answer that worked. Don't know down voted it at first place. :D